# How to display this kind of receive NSXMLParser data

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, nsxmlparser

here's a sample of xml code:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p style="direction: rtl">בפייסבוק הישראלי תמצאו, לצד תמונות החתולים והסרטונים הוויראליים גם אינספור תלונות, טרוניות וביקורת נגד חברות ומותגים שונים. חלק מהפרסומים מוצדקים, וזוכים לשיתופים לייקים ולעתים אף למענה של המותג נגדו מתלוננים הגולשים, וחלק קטנוניים עד כדי גיחוך וסביר יותר שהם פשוט בדיחות על חשבון התלונות הרבות שמתפרסמות להן בפייסבוק בקצב די מסחרר.</p><p><a class="bannerlink" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.b144.co.il/products/%d7%9e%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%93%d7%a1%d7%99_%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%99%d7%9f.aspx?sitecode=60&subsitecode=368&site=WEB 3.0   pareto" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'b144_8', 'post', 'BannerLink']);">כל מהנדסי הבניין באתר b144</a></p>
<p style="direction: rtl">היום נתקלנו בסיפור קורע לב (אבל לא באמת) מצד הגולשת תמר צ&#8217;קרטש לוי <a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151371867297006&amp;set=o.128891317150327&amp;type=1&amp;theater" target="_blank">שהתלוננה בפירוט ובאריכות בדף של גלידות נסטלה על בעיה רצינית אליה יש להתייחס בכובד ראש</a>: מיעוט סוכריות הגומי בשלגוני &quot;גומיגם&quot; שמשווקים על-ידי החברה. צ&#8217;קרטש לוי כתבה:</p>
<p style="direction: rtl">&quot;בסך הכל אני מרוצה מהמוצרים שלכם וקונה הרבה מהם, אך יש משהו אחד שחוזר על עצמו ושמתי לב אליו כבר לפני זמן רב והחלטתי להצטרף גם למהלך החברתי החדש ולכתוב לכם פה.   <br />במוצר המצליח שלכם, ״גומיגם״, גלידת סורבה בטעם פירות המשלב בתוכו סוכריות גומי, אין יותר מ-3 סוכריות גומי. מסקר נרחב שערכתי בקרב חתך אוכלוסייה רחב, מרבית האנשים רוכשים מוצר זה בשל סוכריות הגומי המוצפנות בתוכו, ומתאכזבים כל פעם מחדש מכך שאין יותר מ-3 סוכריות.    <br />כל פעם מחדש אני מרגישה מרומה.    <br />תודה רבה על ההקשבה, אשמח אם תיקחו זאת לתשומת ליבכם ותטפלו בבעיה.&quot;</p>
<p style="direction: rtl"><a href="http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/archives/87871/gumigam" rel="attachment wp-att-87872"><img style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-87872" border="0" alt="gumigam" src="http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gumigam.png" width="560" height="330" /></a></p>
<p style="direction: rtl">הפוסט זכה לאלפי לייקים ומאות שיתופים, ובתגובות הצטרפו רבים לתלונתה של תמר:</p>
<p style="direction: rtl">הבלוגר עמרי חיון כתב: &quot;אני איתך אחותי! המחאה הכי צודקת מאז קיץ 2011&quot; ועמו הסכימה גם סיון סגל שציינה ש:&quot;מעולם לא היה פוסט חשוב יותר מזה בפייסבוק&quot;.</p>
<p style="direction: rtl">עורכת הדין רות גדרון תהתה: &quot;מי אמר שצריכים להיות יותר מ3 ?!?!?&quot; ומארק שפילמן הציע להחליף את שם המוצר ל&quot;זובי גם&quot; בגלל האכזבה הקשה שבמיעוט סוכריות הגומי.&quot; גם לאיתי סבח היו תלונות על שם המוצר וההטעיה שהוא יוצר. &quot;הכי הזוי שקוראים לזה גומיגם ספארי.. אני עוד לא ראיתי ספארי עם שלוש חיות. בפארק ליד הבית שלי יש יותר משלוש חיות וזה לא כולל את הערסים!&quot;</p>
<p style="direction: rtl">כמובן שחלק מהמגיבים החליטו שמדובר בתלונה רצינית והטיחו במפרסמת הפוסט שהיא מתעלמת מהבעיות הקשות במדינה, כמו ניצולי השואה ונגע האלימות, ומתעסקת בתפל. לכם, קוראים יקרים, אנחנו לא צריכים להסביר שהתעסקות בתפל, קטנוניות ובזבוז זמן הם מהשימושים הנפוצים בישראל לרשת פייסבוק, פרט אולי למשחקים בה ותמונות חיות המחמד לאימוץ. סטטוס התלונה הזה הוא לא יותר מהקצנה סטירית.</p>
<p style="direction: rtl">למרות זאת, הצלחנו לאתר בסבך 800 התגובות לפוסט את התגובה של חברת נסטלה, שהגיבה באופן הכי צפוי ומשעמם: ביקשה את פרטיה של המתלוננת בשביל ליצור עמה קשר לבירור פרטי התלונה ואולי גם ייתנו פיצוי. חבל, אנחנו דווקא היינו שמחים לראות אותם משחקים יחד עם שאר הטרולים בשרשור וכותבים משהו כמו &quot;צמצמנו את מספר חיות הגומי בשלגונים בגלל עלות המחייה ובניסיון לצמצם את מפגת ההשמנה והסכרת בקרב ילדים&quot;.</p>
<p style="direction: rtl"><a href="http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/archives/87871/nestle" rel="attachment wp-att-87873"><img style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-87873" border="0" alt="nestle" src="http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/nestle.png" width="395" height="187" /></a></p>
<p style="direction: rtl">
<p style="direction: rtl">(תודה למוטי פנחסי ששלח)</p>
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/holes/~4/8a7HU6h5VbA" height="1" width="1"/>]]></content:encoded>
```

i want to know how can i display that xml like in this picture, with the links:

[image: sample pic]

should i need to use UIwebview somehow? or there is another way?
thanks in advance!
(sorry for the language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a UIWebView is one approach.  You would specify the web view's URL as a file that: a) is preinstalled on the iPhone or b) loaded over the internet.

Another option is to use a UITextView.  You would specify the content of the text view by assigning your content to the `text` property.

[edit] If your 'xml code' is the result of an parser running on the iOS device, then write the parsed output to file and then create the UIWebView to reference that file.  Like:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:
       [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://<path-to-file>"]]];
```

or alternately, I believe, leave the 'xml code' as a string and try:

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString: <the-xml-code-as-a-string> baseURL: ...]
```

[edit]

I tested this and it worked.  Here is what my iOS simulator showed:
[image]

and here is the code:

```
static NSString *message = @"<p style=\"direction: rtl\">בפייסבוק הישראלי תמצאו, לצד תמונות החתולים והסרטונים הוויראליים גם אינספור תלונות, טרוניות וביקורת נגד חברות ומותגים שונים. חלק מהפרסומים מוצדקים, וזוכים לשיתופים לייקים ולעתים אף למענה של המותג נגדו מתלוננים הגולשים, וחלק קטנוניים עד כדי גיחוך וסביר יותר שהם פשוט בדיחות על חשבון התלונות הרבות שמתפרסמות להן בפייסבוק בקצב די מסחרר.</p><p><a class=\"bannerlink\" rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.b144.co.il/products/%d7%9e%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%93%d7%a1%d7%99_%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%99%d7%9f.aspx?sitecode=60&subsitecode=368&site=WEB 3.0   pareto\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'b144_8', 'post', 'BannerLink']);\">כל מהנדסי הבניין באתר b144</a></p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">היום נתקלנו בסיפור קורע לב (אבל לא באמת) מצד הגולשת תמר צ&#8217;קרטש לוי <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151371867297006&amp;set=o.128891317150327&amp;type=1&amp;theater\" target=\"_blank\">שהתלוננה בפירוט ובאריכות בדף של גלידות נסטלה על בעיה רצינית אליה יש להתייחס בכובד ראש</a>: מיעוט סוכריות הגומי בשלגוני &quot;גומיגם&quot; שמשווקים על-ידי החברה. צ&#8217;קרטש לוי כתבה:</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">&quot;בסך הכל אני מרוצה מהמוצרים שלכם וקונה הרבה מהם, אך יש משהו אחד שחוזר על עצמו ושמתי לב אליו כבר לפני זמן רב והחלטתי להצטרף גם למהלך החברתי החדש ולכתוב לכם פה.   <br />במוצר המצליח שלכם, ״גומיגם״, גלידת סורבה בטעם פירות המשלב בתוכו סוכריות גומי, אין יותר מ-3 סוכריות גומי. מסקר נרחב שערכתי בקרב חתך אוכלוסייה רחב, מרבית האנשים רוכשים מוצר זה בשל סוכריות הגומי המוצפנות בתוכו, ומתאכזבים כל פעם מחדש מכך שאין יותר מ-3 סוכריות.    <br />כל פעם מחדש אני מרגישה מרומה.    <br />תודה רבה על ההקשבה, אשמח אם תיקחו זאת לתשומת ליבכם ותטפלו בבעיה.&quot;</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\"><a href=\"http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/archives/87871/gumigam\" rel=\"attachment wp-att-87872\"><img style=\"background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px\" class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-87872\" border=\"0\" alt=\"gumigam\" src=\"http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gumigam.png\" width=\"560\" height=\"330\" /></a></p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">הפוסט זכה לאלפי לייקים ומאות שיתופים, ובתגובות הצטרפו רבים לתלונתה של תמר:</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">הבלוגר עמרי חיון כתב: &quot;אני איתך אחותי! המחאה הכי צודקת מאז קיץ 2011&quot; ועמו הסכימה גם סיון סגל שציינה ש:&quot;מעולם לא היה פוסט חשוב יותר מזה בפייסבוק&quot;.</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">עורכת הדין רות גדרון תהתה: &quot;מי אמר שצריכים להיות יותר מ3 ?!?!?&quot; ומארק שפילמן הציע להחליף את שם המוצר ל&quot;זובי גם&quot; בגלל האכזבה הקשה שבמיעוט סוכריות הגומי.&quot; גם לאיתי סבח היו תלונות על שם המוצר וההטעיה שהוא יוצר. &quot;הכי הזוי שקוראים לזה גומיגם ספארי.. אני עוד לא ראיתי ספארי עם שלוש חיות. בפארק ליד הבית שלי יש יותר משלוש חיות וזה לא כולל את הערסים!&quot;</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">כמובן שחלק מהמגיבים החליטו שמדובר בתלונה רצינית והטיחו במפרסמת הפוסט שהיא מתעלמת מהבעיות הקשות במדינה, כמו ניצולי השואה ונגע האלימות, ומתעסקת בתפל. לכם, קוראים יקרים, אנחנו לא צריכים להסביר שהתעסקות בתפל, קטנוניות ובזבוז זמן הם מהשימושים הנפוצים בישראל לרשת פייסבוק, פרט אולי למשחקים בה ותמונות חיות המחמד לאימוץ. סטטוס התלונה הזה הוא לא יותר מהקצנה סטירית.</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">למרות זאת, הצלחנו לאתר בסבך 800 התגובות לפוסט את התגובה של חברת נסטלה, שהגיבה באופן הכי צפוי ומשעמם: ביקשה את פרטיה של המתלוננת בשביל ליצור עמה קשר לבירור פרטי התלונה ואולי גם ייתנו פיצוי. חבל, אנחנו דווקא היינו שמחים לראות אותם משחקים יחד עם שאר הטרולים בשרשור וכותבים משהו כמו &quot;צמצמנו את מספר חיות הגומי בשלגונים בגלל עלות המחייה ובניסיון לצמצם את מפגת ההשמנה והסכרת בקרב ילדים&quot;.</p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\"><a href=\"http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/archives/87871/nestle\" rel=\"attachment wp-att-87873\"><img style=\"background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px\" class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-87873\" border=\"0\" alt=\"nestle\" src=\"http://www.holesinthenet.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/nestle.png\" width=\"395\" height=\"187\" /></a></p>\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">\n\
<p style=\"direction: rtl\">(תודה למוטי פנחסי ששלח)</p>";

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self.webView loadHTMLString: message
                       baseURL: [[NSURL alloc] init]];
}
```

Comment: but how can i disply it on UIWebView? i get string from the parser..
and can i have the blue links like in the image i posted?

im pretty new to ios develompent so a sample or explamtion would be great..

Comment: The parser is running on the iOS device?

Comment: [myWebView loadHTMLString: <the-xml-code-as-a-string> baseURL: ...]
what should i pass in the "baseURL"?

Comment: Good question.  Not sure actually.

Comment: so how do you suggest me to display it?
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://<path-to-file>"]]];

this one is also not helps me becuase i dont have a URL to pass, i have only the string from the parser.

Comment: Try using loadHTMLString: but create a baseURL like: `[[NSURL alloc] init]` Maybe that will work.

Comment: Worked for me.  Try the above.  Please 'upvote' and 'check' as solution.  Good luck.